# Stateless function components in Mobx?

Tags: reactjs, mobx

I am trying to make a stateless component. I wrapped it in a

```
import { observer } from "mobx-react";

export const Test = observer(({ props}) => (
  <span>
    test
  </span>
));
```

I get errors like `"react-dom.development.js:16419 Uncaught ReferenceError: React is not defined"`

```
import {Test} from "../../../Test";

  <Test/>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe it's as simple as importing React, try:

```
import React from 'react';
```

Comment: lol, yea it was that simple. I was so fixated on thinking that since it is a stateless component it does not need React

Comment: As a clue, if you are using JSX anywhere then you need React there.